# why there is some space in this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I use this code for making this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAA"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/dialog_button_bg"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

rouded_whiite.bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
            android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

But when I do this I have see this result. As you can see there is some margin below of red button. I didn't set any margin or something but there is some space there. What should I do here for getting exact result as in fist image.

[image]

Comment: android:layout_margin="20dp" ?

Comment: Have you tried to set `android:padding="0dp"` in your `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: why are you using a nested linearlayout if you can implement it using RelativeLayout only ?

Comment: Hi See My Answer You Give  android:layout_centerInParent="true" To LinearLayout Thts Why The some margin below of red button.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

instead of

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

and remove margin from bottom...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin from your `RelativeLayout` and make your `LinearLayout` gravity `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg">
```

Comment: it didn't work out bro. (( The space buttom below is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

it is because of this. remove the imageview from the linear layout and set in the relative layout and give property as alignparent bottom and for the linear layout give alignparent top and above the image view property,

Answer (score 0):

## Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAA"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/dialog_button_bg"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using drawable for imageview as .png or .jpg use the following drawable for your image may be it would help. save this as backgroung_bg.xml or anything else as you wish

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape >
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#CF4647"/>
        <padding android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

when you apply this you would get following warning just ignore and run it. if you need gradient type of color ask me

*The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)*